# Map returns strange results

Tags: apex

My systemdebug statement return strange results, and I am not sure why. I am getting

```
femaIdsMap : {a2d2fadfdsadf=123456789}
```

And I am expecitng to  see:

femaIdsMap : {a2d2fadfdsadf, 123456789}

```
Map<id, string> femaIdsMap = new Map<id, string>();
        for (Fema_Data__c fd : [Select id, FEMA_ID__c from FEMA_DATA__c where FEMA_ID__c !=null and Account__c = null and Contact__c = null]){

            femaIdsMap.put(fd.id, fd.FEMA_ID__c);

        }
        System.debug('femaIdsMap :' + femaIdsMap);
```

Where does the "=" come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply how a map is printed/serialized.

Since a map is a collection of key-value pairs, the serialization needs to convey that the key and value are related.

`{a, 1, b, 2, c, 3}` looks like a list
`{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3}` shows that there is a correlation between the letters and numbers. I think I'd prefer if apex serialized maps using `=>` to show correlation (to match the syntax used to set initial values in a map), but a simple equals sign still does the job I suppose.

Comment: Thank you Derek, this makes a ton of sense. I should have thought of that. I guess I was hoping my larger problem would be related to this, but I guess not.